# AutoIt opening and closing link with two browsers

Tags: autoit

i am trying to make a script that will open a a link in browser and click few positions.

I am new to AutoIt so please don't judge me, just try to help.

So far I've got this as a test and i have no idea how to specify a browser.
I want to open one link in Opera and another in Chrome

```
$sUrl='http://localhost/userpanel'
ShellExecute($sUrl)
$hwnd=WinActivate("UCP Receive Bonus")
WinWaitActive($hwnd,'','5')
Sleep(5000)
MouseClick("left", 1410,205, 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your system-configuration, but normally this should work

```
ShellExecute('safari.exe', 'www.google.com')
ShellExecute('firefox.exe', 'www.google.com')
ShellExecute('chrome.exe', 'www.google.com')
```